# Reading large table by chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table generated on a server and I connect to it using a presto client as follows:

```
conn = presto.connect('hostname',port)
db = "some_large_table"
```

What I would like to do is  to read in 1 chunk at a time then do my processing and append that chunk to an existing df. Ie:

```
sql = "select column1, .. column20 limit 100"
chunk_count = 0
dfs = []


for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, chunksize=10) :
    chunk_count +=1
    dfs.append(chunk)

print(dfs[['column1', 'column2']])
```

The print dfs only shows 10 rows. Which Means its not appending.

Comment: dfs should be an empty dataframe if this is the desired behavior that way you just keep appending to it, not a list

Comment: dfs is a list. One could do things like dfs[0], dfs[2:4] etc to select items or range of items (rows in this case). One cannot index it with a string. If the elements support indexing with string, one could do `print([ [elem[key] for key in [ 'field1', 'field2' ]] for elem in dfs[n:m] ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my query I limited the number of rows to 10. For some reason df_full.append() does not work, I changed it to df_full = df_full.append() and it works fine.

```
sql = "select*...limit 10"
df_source = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, chunksize=2)
chunk_count = 0

df_list = []
df_full = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)

for chunk in df_source:
    df_list.append(chunk)

for df_item in df_list:
    df_full = df_full.append(df_item, ignore_index = True)

print(df_full)
```

Result:

```
[10 rows x 38 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Appending to dataframes is really slow and should be avoided. Pandas does not do in-place appending. The dataframe is always copied to a new version.

So in your code, you could do this:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame()  #empty dataframe

 # then in the loop:

    dfs = dfs.append(chunk)
```

And that would work. If you don't have very many chunks, then it is not bad. But as dfs grows, it will start to slow down to a crawl.

I find it is best to append lod (list of dict) and then cast all at once into a dataframe, if you want one big dataframe.

Thus:

```
sql = "select column1, .. column20 limit 100"
chunk_count = 0
lod = []

for chunk_df in pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, chunksize=10) :
   chunk_count += 1
   lod += chunk_df.to_dict(orient='records')
   
dfs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lod)

print(f"processed {chunk_count} chunks.\n", dfs[['column1', 'column2']])
```

This method does not get slower as you go, because lists can append quickly,
and then the lod is converted to dfs in one shot.

Answer (score -1):

Well I can't be sure that this will work without more context but I can tell you that your issue arises because dfs is a list of data frames not a data frame... That said with this approach you will assign dfs to be equal to your first query and append subsequent querys to that result.

```
sql = "select column1, .. column20 limit 100"
chunk_count = 0

for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, chunksize=10) :
    chunk_count +=1
    try:
        dfs.append(chunk)
    except:
        dfs = chunk

print(dfs[['column1', 'column2']])
```

Comment: this won’t work either, the issue is the brackets, when you have multiple columns you want to index you need to put them inside their own list which you then index with. it would look something like dfs[[col1, col2]]

Comment: I added what @gold_cy mentioned and that successfully let me print out the 2 columns. But when I do.. only 10 rows print. I would expect there to be 100 as each chunk is appended to the next

Comment: that’s also because this answer doesn’t define the variable dfs so every loop the except statement kicks in and sets the variable to be just 10 rows.

Comment: @gold_cy yes that appears to be whats happening. I initialized the df before the loop as `dfs = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_name)` where I added column names as reflected in my query. I don't think the append works. When I print dfs I only get the column names.

Comment: @Gold_cy dfs is defined in the except so it will only throw the error once... Also I edited the answer to include the double squares.

Comment: Have you tried the code, it only prints out the number of rows that are in the chunksize. So dfs.append(chunk) is not really appending its just jumping down to dfs=chunk

Comment: when I make it `dfs = dfs.append(chunk)` it works, so just add the `dfs =`